# Прижать к верхнему краю текст в input

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, input

Создал поле для ввода, но текст в нем начинает печататся с центра. Как исправить? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, для этих целей, вам нужен тег `<textarea></textarea>`

Answer (score 4):

Для такого рода элементов есть тег `<textarea></textarea>`.
Если же вам нужен именно `input`, то задайте не высоту, а `padding`:

```css
input {
    padding: 0 0 200px 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Тебе +1 Никита, так как ты более подробнее расписал с двумя вариантами